# Play! framefork renders incorrectly arguments from a controller to a view

Tags: playframework

My controller action:

```
public static void showGalery() {
    ...
    render(subPhotos, size);
}
```

A part of my view:

```
<img id="mainImage" 
     src="${subPhotos.get(0).path}" 
     class="galery-main-photo" 
     onmouseover="toolTip(${subPhotos.get(0).description});"
     onmouseout="toolTip();" />
```

Path passed correcly from an action, but description incorrectly (javascript function doesn't call). If I write `${subPhotos.get(0).description.length()}` then Javascript function are called and passed a correct length of a string.
From DB got a correct description.

Thanks,
Sergey

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think Sergey is saying that if he adds the length method then the value is displayed in the tooltip but if he just leaves the description then nothing appears.

Comment: @Codemwnci Not sure what you're saying........................................................

Answer (score 1):

Because the description is a string, you must surround it with quotes.  Be sure to use single quotes, because the HTML attribute is using double quotes.

```
onmouseover="toolTip('${subPhotos.get(0).description}');"
```